# How do I switch from my MainWindow to a secondary page?

Tags: c++, qt, button, user-interface

I am trying to switch my main page to another on a button click.  I have created a new Qt class form called `SecPage`.  Below is how I try to show the new page in the `onclick()` method.  When I build the program it crashes when I click the specified button.

```
void MainWindow::on_button_clicked() {
  SecPage *second;
  second->show();
}
```

Comment: Between `SecPage *second;` and `second->show();` you probably want to do a `second = new SecPage();`.  Or, if it's a modal, just declare the SecPage object on the stack, and use it directly: `SecPage second;` and `second.show();`.

Comment: The use of a dangling pointer is undefined behavior. Sure it can crash. You're lucky it does. It would be way worse if it didn't crash but silently corrupted some data structures and sent you on a wild debugging goose chase :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not setting the pointer declared as 'SecPage *second' to anything valid.  You need to do something like this:

```
SecPage *second = new SecPage();
second->show();
// .. and delete pointer second somewhere...
```

Although if it's a modal dialog, you're better off simply declaring it as a stack variable:

```
SecPage second;
second.setModal(true);
second.show();
```

Then you don't have to worry about a pointer at all.

Comment: In your second example, the dialog will be destroyed immediately as it will go out of scope right after `show()`. You either have to make it a member variable, or use [`QDialog::exec`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qdialog.html#exec).